# Taking a proper class as a model for Set Theory

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, inner-model-theory

When I am reading through higher Set Theory books I am frequently met with statements such as '$V$ is a model of ZFC' or '$L$ is a model of ZFC' where $V$ is the Von Neumann Universe, and $L$ the Constructible Universe. For instance, in Jech's 'Set Theory' pg 176, in order to prove the consistency of the Axiom of Choice with ZF, he constructs $L$ and shows that it models the ZF axioms plus AC.

However isn't this strictly inaccurate as $V$ and $L$ are proper classes? For instance, by this very method we might as well take it as a $Theorem$ in ZFC that ZFC is consistent since $V$ models ZFC. However this is obviously impossible as ZFC cannot prove its own consistency. I highly doubt that Jech would make a mistake in such classic textbook, so I must be missing something.

How could we, for instance, show Con(ZF) $\implies$ Con(ZF + AC) without invoking the use of proper classes? I imagine, for instance, that we would start with some (set sized) model $M$ of ZFC and apply some sort of 'constructible universe' construction to $M$.

Comment: In ZFC, the (formal) satisfaction relation $\models$ is only defined for set-models. Moreover, in order to deduce the consistency of a theory from the existence of a model, you need to have a set-model. For this reason, the fact that "V/L is a model of ZFC", which cannot be expressed in ZFC with a single statement, does not say anything about the consistency of ZFC. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772116/why-doesnt-v-is-a-model-of-zf-imply-consistency-of-zf/772118#772118) is a related question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What is shown in the cases you mention is not that the model is a model of ZFC, made as a single statement, but rather the *scheme* of statements that the model satisfies every individual axiom of ZFC, as a separate statement for each axiom.

The difference is between asserting "$L$ is a model of ZFC" and the scheme of statements "$L$ satisfies $\phi$" for every axiom $\phi$ of ZFC.

This difference means that from the scheme, you cannot deduce Con(ZFC).

For the proof that Con(ZF) implies Con(ZFC), one assumes Con(ZF), and so there is a set model $M$ of ZF. The $L$ of this model, which is a class in $M$ but a set for us in the meta-theory, is a model of ZFC, since it satisfies every individual axiom of ZFC. So we've got a model of ZFC, and thus Con(ZFC).

Comment: I somewhat disagree with your last paragraph. The point of the proof is that you get a stronger result. You don't just assume there is a model of ZF and produce a model of ZFC. You actually prove a stronger result, that ZF itself proves any finite number of axioms of ZFC hold in L. Of course, that requires a meta-theoretic jump to conclude from Con(ZF) to Con(ZFC), but it is in fact *more* than saying "Assume there is a set model, produce another set model".

Comment: So, are you saying that Jech was being slightly unrigorous in his proof of Con(ZF) implies Con(ZFC)? If so, do you have any references to where I can find such a rigorous proof?

Comment: @Elie: Probably the old Kunen book; you might to check Felgner's Models of ZF set theory; and since judging by your name there's a good chance you can read Hebrew, you might want to see if Matti Rubin's notes on axiomatic set theory from the early 2000s are still online.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, of course the set models are closely related, in that the ZFC model is the $L$ of the ZF model, so whatever extra you are getting is gotten that way, because of the closeness of the models. I don't agree that your way of talking about it is stronger, since you are talking about a scheme of proofs, and this takes place in the meta-theory.

Comment: @ElieBen-Shlomo I don't view Jech's argument as unrigorous, since I interpret him to be saying the same as what I said.

Comment: Just to check that I understand correctly: the key point here is that ZFC is not finitely axiomatizable right ? It means that checking in the meta theory that each axiom is satisfied is different from checking internally that " for all axiom in the recursively enumerated sets of axioms, L satisfies it " ? Or is there already a distinction to be made for a single axiom or a finitely axiomatizable theory ?

Comment: @SimonHenry There is a little more to it than that, since after all, GBC is finitely axiomatizable, but we don't say that GBC implies Con(GBC) just because in GBC we can prove that the universe itself is a model of GBC. The point is that the argument that exists-a-model implies consistency requires having a satisfaction class or truth predicate for the model (since one proves by induction on proofs that the proofs are truth-preserving with respect to the satisfaction class, and contradictions are never true with respect to a truth predicate).

Comment: But in ZFC or GBC we are only ensured truth predicates for set models, not proper class models. Meanwhile, in Kelley-Morse set theory, we do have first-order truth predicates for the class models, and thus the argument about L does show Con(ZFC) in KM. See http://jdh.hamkins.org/km-implies-conzfc/.

Comment: Joel, I disagree with your claim that this is not a stronger result. From a model of PA you get a model of PA+not Con(PA). But there is no "reasonable way" to define that model within the natural numbers. There is no internal way through which PA proves that every finite part of PA is consistent with not Con(PA).  The situation with ZF and ZFC is different (although admittedly the situation is different because both AC and its negation are equiconsistent over ZF).

Comment: You are objecting to something I am not asserting. Your stronger assertion amounts to the same as what I call the scheme of assertions that L satisfies every individual axiom of ZFC. Of course this is stronger than the arithmetic implication that Con(ZF) implies Con( ZFC). I think we agree about this.

Comment: Meanwhile, every model of PA does have a definable model of PA plus not Con(PA), since one can use the Henkin model of the left most branch through the tree of attempts to build a complete consistent Henkin theory.

Comment: Thanks ! your blog post really made things clearer to me. I was actually wondering for some time what was the precise technical point that made GBC and KM different regarding the consistency of ZFC. Now I know.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, that is true. But note that in its nature statements like $\operatorname{Con}(T)$ are *meta-theoretic* statements. So when we say that $V$ is a model of $\sf ZF$, we mean that in the meta-theory it is a model of $\sf ZF$.

This is often something which is not stressed enough in introductions to $V$ and relative consistency results: when we prove that $L$ is a model of $\sf ZFC$, we do not "just prove a meta-theoretic result", we in fact prove a stronger statement:

> There is a formula $L$ in the language of set theory which defines a class that is provably transitive and contains all the ordinals, and for every axiom $\varphi$ of $\sf ZFC$, $\sf ZF\vdash\varphi^\it L$.

So not only you have this model, but in fact $\sf ZF$ itself prove that each axiom of $\sf ZFC$ holds in $L$.

---

Let me also share, in my first course on axiomatic set theory, which was given by the late Mati Rubin, we had proved that $\sf ZF-Reg$ and $\sf ZF$ are equiconsistent by practically proving that $\sf PRA$ proves that if there is a contradiction in $\sf ZF$, then there is one in $\sf ZF-Reg$.

Of course, the same can be done with $\sf ZF$ and $\sf ZFC$. And it is much more annoying than using the model theoretic approach. Sometimes with impunity when it comes to class models.

Comment: One might say that Mati was overly pedantic in his teaching methods, by the way. I mean, I would say that, and I know a few other people who would say otherwise.

Comment: Can I ask to clarify something? Did you actually obtain a proof within PRA itself that Con(ZF−F) implies Con(ZF)? Or is it that you prove in ZFC that a proof exists in PRA (as seemingly stated in your answer)? Similarly, what is the weakest well-known system over which we have an actual proof for "Con(Z) implies Con(ZFC)", or at least can write a program to generate the proof? Thanks!

Comment: The former. The point is that the process of moving from the code of $\varphi$ to the code of the relativization of $\varphi$ to WF (or V) is itself a primitive recursive process. So if you assume in PRA that ZF proves a contradiction, the process of transforming this to a proof of contradiction from ZF-Reg is recursive: just apply the relativization function finitely many times.

Answer (score -7):

The class $V$ of all sets is not a model of $ZFC$, because it is a proper class, not a set.

A model of $ZFC$ is a **set** (or *small class*) $U\in V$ which satisfies all the axioms of $ZFC$ when these axioms are restricted or relativized to $U$, even though $U$ does not include all the sets of the $ZFC$ universe.

If a model $U$ of $ZFC$ exists within the universe $V$ of $ZFC$, then its cardinality is "inaccessible" with respect to the universe $V$. Conversely, if an inaccessible cardinal exists in the universe $V$ of $ZFC$, then a small class, or set $U\in V$ exists, which is a model of $ZFC$.

The existence of a model $U$ within the universe $V$ of $ZFC$ implies that $ZFC$ is consistent. $ZFC$ would be *inconsistent* if its axioms could prove the existence of a model of itself within itself.

I fear that the meta-theorems, meta-theory, and other meta-language are unnecesssary and ill-defined, unless in the universe $V$ of $ZFC$ we are speaking of the properties of a possible model $U, U\in V, U\subsetneqq V$ where the original axioms of $ZFC$ have been restricted to a $U$.

Comment: This does not add to the answers already appearing, with the exception that it adds mistakes (e.g. inaccessibility is only obtained when one restricts to second-order ZFC; being a model of ZFC need not be using the real $\in$ of $V$, but rather it can be using some arbitrary binary relation on the set $U$, etc.)

Comment: "Second-order ZFC" -- No. You are confusing things unnecessarily again. Of course another relation may be used, but if there is a model then it may be represented by the standard relation $\in$ on a set $U$, (where $U\in V$ and $U\subsetneqq V$.)

Comment: Again? When did I confuse things unnecessarily before? And no, you are absolutely wrong. But it seems impossible to get you to admit that, so I'm going to stop trying.

Comment: A model $(U,\epsilon)$ is isomorphic to one of the form $(U',\in)$ (a "standard model") iff $\epsilon$ is a well-founded relation. This is not necessarily satisfied for an arbitrary model. (And that's true even though the model believes itself to be well-founded. It can be mistaken about that!) Even worse: if ZF(C) is consistent, then $Con(ZFC)+$"There is no standard model" is also consistent, i.e. it is perfectly possible that, while there are models of ZFC, *all* of them are ill-founded.

Comment: @JohannesHahn: How does this post "Looks OK"?

Comment: A proof of the fact Johannes mentioned: let $M$ be a model of ZFC + Con(ZFC) + "There is a standard model of ZFC," let $\alpha$ be the thing $M$ thinks is the least height of a standard model of ZFC, and consider $L_\alpha$ ...

Comment: Meanwhile, your claim "If a model U of ZFC exists within the universe V of ZFC, then its cardinality is "inaccessible" with respect to the universe V" is false as observed above. It's not even true for models of the form $V_\alpha$ - [not every worldly cardinal is inaccessible](http://cantorsattic.info/Worldly) (assuming they exist). I believe you're thinking of *universes* in the sense of category theory, but those (as Asaf says) are really about **second-order** ZFC in a precise (e.g. in a universe, powersets need to be computed correctly).

Comment: (In my first comment above, it should say "$L_\alpha^M$" rather than "$L_\alpha$," of course (the latter doesn't really make sense, although it's clear what's meant). A bit too late for me to edit it, unfortunately.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila There is no button for "Not a great post, but doesn't necessarily need to be deleted". That's what downvotes are for as I understand the system.

Comment: @JohannesHahn: How is a post which only introduces mistakes, where the person posting insists being correct is useful for anything?

Comment: (Sorry to keep spamming comments, but further on the universe issue, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2563996/worldly-vs-inaccessible-cardinals-why-different/2564027) may be helpful.)

Comment: @JohannesHahn if $\epsilon$ is not a well-founded relation, then a model $U,\epsilon$ cannot be a model of $ZFC$, because the axioms of $ZFC$ require $\in$ to be well-founded.

Comment: Unfortunately, the latest comment, claiming that the membership relation of a model of ZFC has to be well-founded, is another error. I agree, though, with @JohannesHahn that the post doesn't need to be deleted. I've seen the same errors elsewhere, so it may be useful for some readers to see them here along with the comments and downvotes, which (I think) suffice to make it clear that they are errors.

Comment: @JustinaColmena Your most recent comment again makes the mistake of conflating second-order ZFC and (first-order) ZFC. By [the compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem), there is no way to rule out ill-founded models in a first-order way. The axiom of regularity prevents the existence of descending $\in$-sequences *which are definable inside the model*, but this is only "internal well-foundedness." The situation here is identical to that of [nonstandard models of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic).

Comment: By contrast, of course, every model of *second-order* ZFC is well-founded, but that's a very different thing. (Similarly, *second-order* Peano arithmetic has no nonstandard models, but first-order Peano arithmetic has lots by the compactness theorem.)